# time stamp in multiple sheets in workbook

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a daily worksheet with 6 sheets but only the first 4 do I need to enter the date just before they run the back up archive so in cell A1 todays date is added.  All daily sheets have todays date and day i.e 08.09.17 Friday as the title but they can be made many months in advance so when doing the back up (already working) I need todays date in cell A1 for all 4 sheets so they get moved to correct archive sheet for the date, which is what back up script is using to put in archive sheet date column so we can track customers daily usage.
I am using this script but getting a blank output:-

```
    function timeStamp() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
     var sheetNames = ['1st sheet name', '2nd sheet name', '3rd sheet name', 
     '4th sheet name'];
     .setActiveCell(A1));
     .setValue(new Date());
```

Comment: There is an issue with your code. You are missing some lines. Like you have `.setActiveCell(A1));` it has extra `)` etc...

Comment: This is essentially the same question as this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103225/including-the-worksheet-title-in-the-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103225/including-the-worksheet-title-in-the-spreadsheet)

Comment: @bulbus could you please expand?  I have tried .setActiveCell(A1) with and without the ; afterwards and with and without the ) and get error each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fit response to Paul's question in comments, so here we go.
Not sure if this is what the final solution is but...

```
function timeStamp() {
   var sheetNames = ['1st sheet name', '2nd sheet name', '3rd sheet name','4th sheet name'];
   for(i=0;i<sheetNames.length;i++)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]).getRange("A1").setValue(new Date())
}
```

A bit of explanation..
`SpreadsheetApp`
 Instance of the Application "Google SpreadSheets"
`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`
 This returns the active SpreadSheet(like Workbook/Full Document),could use `.getActiveSpreadSheet()` as well
`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetNames[i])`
 This returns the Sheet with name `sheetNames[i]`(vis-a-vis Worksheet/Tab)
`.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date())`
 Sets your date in "A1" for respective Sheet

**Just a thought on what you had**
The below would work

```
//You can drop the semicolon here if you want.
var sheetNames = ['1st sheet name', '2nd sheet name', '3rd sheet name', '4th sheet name']; 
//Moved it one line down as the next two lines run off of it by referencing it with a .(well almost)
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
   //If line above is array assignment then no matter what you do you will get syntax error for the below two lines.       
   // You need to pass the address as string, unless A1 is a variable with string address.
  .getActiveCell("A1") 
   //Note that for this to work there should be no semicolons for the two lines of code above this.
  .setValue(new Date()) 
//Semicolon marks the end of statement and thus losing reference to an object and making any .function calls syntax errors
```

Comment: You can replace `getSheetByName(sheetNames[i])` by `getSheets()[i]` if you want only the first four sheets irrespective of their name. I believe that's what you need. If that is the case I can edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the sheets that you want this in are in the same spreadsheet then all you have to do is go to A1 and enter this `=nameOfSpreadsheet()` Yes, I know it's customary to capitalize all of the letters but I generally swim against the currents of following customs. You may capitalize all of them if you wish.

```
function nameOfSpreadsheet()
{
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
}
```

Also of course you will have to put the function into a project in your script editor.  I keep my custom functions like this in a separate project from other functions.

Comment: I have an issue @Cooper that the script is working but takes a few seconds to load the name into the box and so in the archive script i have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018216/simplifying-an-archiving-script it uses the date to enter in the time stamp of the archive sheet.  However if the sheet is closed I am getting the date 01/0/1970 (I assume) because it doesn't have time to load date, can I add this?  if so where?
function testWait(){
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock(); lock.waitLock(300000); 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); lock.releaseLock();